# When should we index a key K1 when a composite index already exists with K1 placed first?

Tags: index

If a table already has an `INDEX (K1, K2, ...)`, when is it a good idea to create an `INDEX(K1)`?

More generally, when `INDEX (K1, K2, K3, ...)` is present, under what circumstances is it a good idead to create one or several of  `INDEX (K1)`, `INDEX (K1, K2)`, aso. ?

Comment: No. The index with short expression is more compact, so scanning by it needs less pages readings. So you must to find the balance. For example, it may be the most optimal to have 2 indexes - full `(K1, K2, ..., K10)` and short `(K1, K2, K3)`. Or 3 indexes (by 1-2, by 1-5 and full)... And, for example, while searching by `1-4` the scanning index by `1-3` plus table scan may be more effective then scanning by full index if `K4` field have a few possible values (for example, it is boolean).

Comment: Its very difficult to determine always unnecessary as it depends on many conditions however generally what you have said is right considering above comments made by Akina.